# How to use a concept for STL containers?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, c++-concepts

Based on this old stack overflow question [How do you define a C++ concept for the standard library containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449592/how-do-you-define-a-c-concept-for-the-standard-library-containers)

I see that it's possible to define a concept for STL containers. However, I am unsure how to actually apply the concept to anything, because it requires 2 containers, container a and container b.

For example, taking the signature of the most upvoted answer

```
template <class ContainerType> 
    concept Container = requires(ContainerType a, const ContainerType b)
```

I've only seen concepts used with just 1 requirement argument, like so

```
//source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints
template<typename T>
concept Hashable = requires(T a)
{
    { std::hash<T>{}(a) } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};
 
struct meow {};
 
// Constrained C++20 function template:
template<Hashable T>
void f(T) {}
//
// Alternative ways to apply the same constraint:
// template<typename T>
//     requires Hashable<T>
// void f(T) {}
//
// template<typename T>
// void f(T) requires Hashable<T> {}
 
int main()
{
    using std::operator""s;
 
    f("abc"s);    // OK, std::string satisfies Hashable
    // f(meow{}); // Error: meow does not satisfy Hashable
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the concepts? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I was just wondering where const b would come from? I thought a would be the object being evaluated by the concept?

Comment: `a` and `b` are simply the values used in the constraint expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of this concept is in fact

```
 template <class ContainerType> 
 concept Container = /* */;
```

which only constrains *one* type `ContainerType`, so the function that applies this concept would be

```
 template <Container C>
 void f(C& c);
```

Comment: Thanks! But where is a and const b coming from?

Comment: They come from the parameters of the requires clause, which means that when there is an instance `a` of type `ContainerType` and an instance `b` of type `const ContainerType&`, they need to satisfy the following constraint expressions

Comment: Would the concept only be evaluated if both ```a``` and ```b``` were present? What if you only had ```a``` of type ```ContainerType``` but no ```b```?

Comment: This has nothing to do with instances, concepts apply to types. when `ContainerType` is instantiated as a specific type, concept needs to check whether the expression in the requires clause is satisfied.

Comment: Or `template <typename T> requires Container<T> void f(C&& c);` or `void f(Container auto&& c);`....