# What should be the definition for the concept of `vector` element type?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdvector, c++-concepts

I am trying to implement `vector` to practice C++ and use C++20 `concept` to constrain `vector`'s element type.

What should be the definition of `concept` (type constraints) for `vector` element type? I think `std::destructible` and `std::move_constructible` are necessary, is there any thing else? And by the way, is using `concept` to constrain `vector`'s element type a bad idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Oh, and please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: See _"...The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container...."_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: This is complicated. Even move-constructability is optional, depending on how you populate the vector.

Comment: @RichardCritten But when I tried to declare `std::vector<S> vec;` where `~S() = delete`, it fails to compile, so I think there is a minimum requirement there and maybe we can specify this minimum requirement. But now I see that according to standard, using `concept` to restrict the element type is a bad idea, thank you.

Comment: There's an implementation of Erasable in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60450396/2610810) of mine

Comment: You need to decide whether you want to go with the same requirement `std::vector` goes with regarding the necessity of making the vector class work, even if the element type is a incomplete type (subject to some limitations regarding the allocator)... If you do want your class to work with incomplete types, the info whether a type is moveable/destructible may not be available in some situations preventing a check for of the concept.

Comment: "so I think there is a minimum requirement there" it is not. You still can allocate a vector such that it is never destroyed, which may be unusual but is completely legal. The requirement of destructibility of elements should go on operations that actually destroy them.

Comment: By the way, sorry for the comments, I posted them in the wrong tab! :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector:

> **The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container**. Generally, it is required that element type meets the requirements of **Erasable**, but many member functions impose **stricter requirements**. This container (but not its members) can be instantiated with an **incomplete element type** if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness requirements.

The *general* minimum requirement is **Erasable** and refer to [How do you define a C++ concept for the standard library containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449592/how-do-you-define-a-c-concept-for-the-standard-library-containers/60450396#60450396) for its implementation.

It is a bad idea to use `concept` to specify this minimum requirement because it does not work with incomplete type.